# Layout of a simple php/mysql website

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, web

Id like to know what the best way of laying out a simple website,
I used switches so that my website would contain the same layout and then just have a little content area that changes as you go to

myserver/index.php?page=home
or
myserver/index.php?page=settings

Here is some code of my switch:
index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
include("config.php");
include("userinfo.php");

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $Page = $_GET['page'];
} else {

} switch ($Page) {

case "logout": {
        require("logout.php");
        include("layout.php");
        break;
    }

case "home": {
        $PageTitle = "Home";
        $PageFileName = "home.php";
        include("layout.php");
        break;
    }

case "music": {
        $PageTitle = "Music";
        $PageFileName = "music.php";
        include("layout.php");
        break;
    }
```

I basicly want to know if the above is a good system for haveing different pages with the same layout but a different content section?

I could also use php includes and include bits and pieces as I need, like a header and side bar, but Id like to know what the best system is? or just any advice or anything.

Thanks,
Jason Russell

Comment: I basically want my site to function like https://www.bitcoins.lc/, just as an example of how the layout stays the same but the content of each page changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use the following structure:

- main directory: has all the files
- includes folder: has two files

Then I create a page, let's call it index.php

```
<?php

include("includes/header.php");

echo "<h1>Page title</h1>";

echo "<p>Page text...</p>";

include("footer.php");

?>
```

I then write a script for each page and keep it all separate.  Your method above seems extremely complicated and you will get very very confused after not very long!

Also, the best way to split the header/footer is to make the layout as you want it in one file.  Then locate the beginning of the main DIV and the end of the main DIV and put the top part in the header, bottom part in the footer.

I tried to keep that as simple as possible.  I hope that helps :)

Comment: Ok that seems to work and help, thanks! But are there any alternative ways though? just out of interest

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can assure you that a huge switch/case is *not* the solution. Look into MVC.

Comment: Yeah I just started with php and html...what is MVC?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller  There are many existing MVC frameworks for PHP that you can start using right away. I prefer Symfony to the rest of them but for a super simple site CodeIgniter is good.