# PHP file layout/design

Tags: php, html, layout

I would like to create a site in php that works the same way that https://www.bitcoins.lc/ does, in terms of it having the same layout on each page but the content would change as you change links/pages, how do I set this up in php with layout.php and index.php and header.php ect?

I was told to read about MVC frameworks but I don't really understand it all.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Jason

Comment: clone of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480947/layout-of-a-simple-php-mysql-website`?

Comment: try read this topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/953675/815295)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The simplest approach is the one described by Sjoerd.
If your page only contains some few elements, there is noting wrong with a switch or if statement.

index.php:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <!-- Wrapper div -->
        <div id="wrapper>


            <!-- Header div -->
            <div id="header">
                <?php
                    include('header.php'); // File containing header code
                ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Content div -->
            <div id="content">


                <!-- Left Colon div -->
                <div id="leftCol">
                    <?php
                        include('leftMenu.php'); // File containing the menu
                    ?>
                </div>


                <!-- Center colon -->
                <div id="centerCol">
                    <?php
                        $page = $_GET['page']; // To get the page

                        if($page == null) {
                            $page = 'index'; // Set page to index, if not set
                        }
                        switch ($page) {

                            case 'index':
                                include('frontPage.php');
                                break;

                            case 'about':
                                include('about.php');
                                break;

                            case 'contact':
                                include('contact.php');
                                break;
                        }

                    ?>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Footer div -->
            <div id="footer">
                <?php
                    include('footer.php'); // File containing the footer
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
    echo "This is header";   
?>
```

leftMenu.php:

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='index.php/?page=index'>Front Page</a>"; // set page to index
    echo "<a href='index.php/?page=about'>About</a>";      // page = about
    echo "<a href='index.php/?page=contact'>Contact</a>";  // page = contact
?>
```

and so on

Comment: You have to do url rewriting and make a front controller. Else your urls are pretty ugly

Answer (score 8):

Here's the approach I generally take to this:

FILES:

- layout.php
- index.php
- views

  - _index.php

layout.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include($childView); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

_index.php:

```
<section>
    Some page content
</section>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    $title = 'Home';
    $childView = 'views/_index.php';
    include('layout.php');
?>
```

Basically, the page itself tells the layout what view to inject into the content area. It's similar to how you would use ASP.NET ContentPlaceholder elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a header and a footer in each page:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>
Welcome to my page
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Put the header and navigation in header.php, and the footer in footer.php.

Comment: This way you have unmatched html tags on header.php and footer.php

Comment: This is the normal way and is not very neat... I wouldn't suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are worried about MVC as you are reading complex documentations about that. I would suggest you to go through a documentation which helps you to easily understand and create an MVC Framework. It will not be good if you move forward with your project without understanding its basics. Please have a look at the following article and let me know if it helps. Feel free to contact if you need any support.

http://www.henriquebarroso.com/how-to-create-a-simple-mvc-framework-in-php/

Comment: Ive started to go through it, but Ive got a problem, I get an error warning in Netbeans with this code:    function loadView($view,$vars="")
 {
  if(is_array($vars) &amp;&amp; count($vars) > 0)
   extract($vars, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");
  require_once('view/'.$view.'.php');
 }

Comment: I did and that works, but I think its a little bit beyond me. I dont quite understand how it all works at the moment

Comment: Ive used the system that hogni89 posted, I understand it and ive set it up quickly and it works for me, but thanks anyway! im going to keep reading about MVC and maybe change in the future.