# Using menu links with GET request, how do I clear the form data?

Tags: php, html, menuitem

I have an an index_test.php with code as follows:

```
            <!-- Center colon -->
            <div id="centerCol">
                <?php
                    $page = $_GET['page']; // To get the page

                    if($page == null) {
                        $page = 'index_test'; // Set page to index_test, if not set
                    }
                    switch ($page) {

                        case 'index_test':
                            include('frontPage.php');
                            break;

                        case 'about':
                            include('about.php');
                            break;

                        case 'contact':
                            include('contact.php');
                            break;
                    }
                ?>
```

and another div with left menu:

```
<?php
unset($_GET);
echo "<a href='index_test.php/?page=index'>Front Page</a>"; // set page to index
echo "<a href='index_test.php/?page=about'>About</a>";      // page = about
echo "<a href='index_test.php/?page=contact'>Contact</a>";  // page = contact
?>
```

[it is based on this stackoverflow answer and yes its pretty simple but in any case I do need to learn more: [PHP file layout/design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483234/php-file-layout-design) ]

What I don't understand is when I click on the links I get:

index_test.php/?page=index

then I click on menu item and I get for example:

index_test.php/index_test.php/?page=about

and then

index_test.php/index_test.php/index_test.php/?page=contact

and so on and its get stuck so how do I clear this and fix this and where (index_test.php or leftMenu.php which called in a menu div)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the problem you are facing. Please explain.

Comment: the problem is the navigation menu is not working as expected basically.  Its seams to be appending url target each time as well as the get value.

Comment: Yes because that is the way you have written it.                                         <a href='index_test.php/?page=contact'>Contact</a>

Answer (score 1):

Use base_url system,

```
$base_url = "http://your_file_path";
```

if you use localhost "http://localhost/your_file_path"

```
<?php
unset($_GET);
echo "<a href='" .$base_url. "index_test.php/?page=index'>Front Page</a>"; // set page to index
echo "<a href='" .$base_url. "index_test.php/?page=about'>About</a>";      // page = about
echo "<a href='" .$base_url. "index_test.php/?page=contact'>Contact</a>";  // page = contact
?>
```

Comment: This works with setting of the base_url.  I know unset should clear $_GET and I tried that without base_url variable, it seams to have no effect (and also tested with setting base_url and without unset  $_GET, doesn't seam to have any effect this way either but for defensive type programming I am tempted to leave that in my code)

Comment: Use redirect() method in php page.

Comment: This worked for me.  Also I used fully qualified domain name rather than a name which is visible to the local Intranet so its compatible with the outside world.... I did not try localhost to see that would also work but thanks, it did resolve my problem.